# Edit files in client app using document id links

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, office-integration, document-id

I activated the document id feature for my site collections. Now I can get two types of links for office documents:

1. Durable links like https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/{Identifier}?e=33sUal and
2. Document Id links like https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID={DocId}

If I send these links and someone uses 1. the document opens in Office for editing and can be saved back to SharePoint.
If 2. is opened, a local copy of the document is created and Office cannot save back changes SharePoint.

This is somehow annoying. I really would like to use Document Id links, because as stated in https://blog.ioz.ch/durable-links-vs-document-id/, durable links are not really durable.

Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the DocID link, you would need to have the end user use Internet Explorer. If not using IE, the browser will download the document.

The DocID link requires an ActiveX control which is only available on IE.

Answer (score 0):

This issue only occurs if the Site Collection Feature "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" has been activated. If you do not activate this feature, then the DocId link will open in Word Online (if you are using SharePoint Online/Office Web Apps). The user can then decide whether to continue editing in Word Online or to switch to Word Desktop via the UI.